# In Visual Studio Code, I am having trouble changing the folder that the power shell terminal runs out of

Tags: powershell, react-native, terminal, visual-studio-code, directory

In VS Code, I cannot figure out how to change the folder that my terminal runs though. I have searched far and wide on the internet with no answer. Whenever I try to run my code, I get an error message saying, "Attribute 'program does not exist ('C:\Projects/app.js')" and I am given the option to open launch.json. In my PowerShell terminal, it is trying to debug through C:\Projects and I think this is where I am messing up. I just have not been able to change it, after reading what feels like thousands of articles. I know the code should run because it is a copy of the code to a tutorial I am taking. I am fairly new to programming and this is my first experience with VS Code, so I am sorry if this is this is a beginner question. Any help and/or advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

I have tried changing things in the launch.json with no luck. However, there is a good chance I am changing the wrongs things.

I believe this is the launch configuration I am using right now.

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/app.js",
        "args": ["projects/path/app.js"],
        "windows": {\
            "args": ["projects\\path\\app.js"]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: You should share your launch config because it's not clear what you are trying to do or what you have tried.

Comment: @RobLourens Following up, how exactly do I do that? Sorry I am new to all of this and just trying to get started.

Comment: `${workspaceFolder}` is the folder currently open in VSCode. Your symptom implies that you've opened folder `C:\Projects`. If that's not where your `app.js` file resides, open VSCode with the folder where it resides instead.

Comment: @mklement0 that is where my problem lies. app.js lies in another folder and I am not sure how to get out of C:\Projects. Do you do that through VS Code or some other way?

Comment: Preferably open the folder in which your `app.js` file resides in Visual Studio Code (`code <folder-path>` or right-click in File Explorer and select `Open with Code`); alternatively, hard-code the full path in `launch.json`.

Comment: @mklement0 that worked thank you!